# Split string column by backslash

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, split, apache-spark-sql

In a dataframe with string column which hold path and filenames (delimiter is backslash), I am trying to split it and get the last item which is filename as a new column. This piece of code I used is as follows:

| Id | path |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | `C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad.exe` |
| 2 | `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe` |
| 3 | `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe` |
| 4 | `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\WINWORD.EXE` |
| 5 | `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE` |

```
df = df.withColumn("filename", f.split(f.col("path"), "\\").getItem(-1))
```

The expected outp:

| Id | path | filename |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | `C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad.exe` | notepad.exe |
| 2 | `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe` | chrome.exe |
| 3 | `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe` | cmd.exe |
| 4 | `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\WINWORD.EXE` | WINWORD.EXE |
| 5 | `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE` | EXCEL |

However, I am getting a runtime error in Pyspark. My initial guess was replacing all backlasheshes with double backslashes in data but it doesn't make any difference. I appreciate any assist to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Use regex extract. Extract values `alphanumerics.alphanumerics` between `\` and the end of string

```
  df=df.withColumn('filename',  regexp_extract(col('path'), '((?<=\\\)\w+\.\w+(?=$))', 1))



+---+-----------------------------------------------------------+-----------+
|Id |path                                                       |filename   |
+---+-----------------------------------------------------------+-----------+
|1  |C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad.exe                     |notepad.exe|
|2  |C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe|chrome.exe |
|3  |C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe                                |cmd.exe    |
|4  |C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\WINWORD.EXE|WINWORD.EXE|
|5  |C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE  |EXCEL.EXE  |
+---+-----------------------------------------------------------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Four backslashes are needed because repeated escapes are required for each level of parsing (Python then Spark):

```
df.withColumn("filename", f.element_at(f.split(f.col("path"), "\\\\"), -1)).show(truncate=False)
+---+-----------------------------------------------------------+-----------+
|Id |path                                                       |filename   |
+---+-----------------------------------------------------------+-----------+
|1  |C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad.exe                     |notepad.exe|
|2  |C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe|chrome.exe |
|3  |C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe                                |cmd.exe    |
|4  |C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\WINWORD.EXE|WINWORD.EXE|
|5  |C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE  |EXCEL.EXE  |
+---+-----------------------------------------------------------+-----------+
```